# can you merge class functions during runtime in c#

Tags: c#, compilation

In c# you can merge dlls at runtime. My question is if you have two classes can you merge individual class methods into one new method? So class a has method a, class b has method b and together they merge to form class c which has one method that is the same as copy and pasting the inner workings of method a and b into a new method? In this both methods have the same arguments and return type.

I do not expect to then run this method, but merely store it in a dll so it does not need to join the application properly.

The class methods chosen would not be known until runtime.

Comment: *"but merely store it in a dll so it does not need to join the application properly."* can you explain more about what you are trying to do with the data, this sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **Ask about the problem you are having that you think merging class functions will solve**, not the problem you have with merging the functions themselves.

Comment: Yes, but please provide more explanation and maybe a small code sample to go by so the question can be properly answered.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist quite yet although it could maybe lead to further experimentation. Its a hypothetical. The reason the thought came about is both with ides and partial classes. In partials multiple classes are merged together and in ides you type another method and given it compiles, the ide automatically generates the dll for you.

Comment: Its not quite an xy problem as there is no solution I am currently after other than to satisfy curiosity. I suppose I could rephrase to how do you dynamically add code or merge like ides but that's not quite what I asked or want to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer I have found is the new roslyn project.